# iOS meta keywords in Arabic

Tags: ios, metadata, keyword, arabic, meta

I am working on an iOS app that is multi language (English & Arabic). Given that the Middle East app markets cannot be localized with additional languages other than English, I have to include Arabic description and keywords.

The meta keywords (100 char.) are tricky as I need to include both English (which is written left to right) and Arabic (which is written right to left).

My questions are follows:

- What do I used to separate the English and Arabic keywords? Do I used the English comma separator (,) or the Arabic comma separator (،).

Is the following example the correct way of doing it (food,guide,طعام,دليل)?

Thanks you.